# How to access files shared from Windows on FreeBSD?

Tags: windows, freebsd, file-sharing, lan

I have a desktop with windows 10 on it, and I have another desktop with FreeBSD on it. No virtualization.

I have shared some folders on Win desktop, which I can access on LAN with other Win10 laptops.

But I am unable to access these folders from freebsd desktop, how can I do it?

I went through older threads, but none of the solutions worked. All of them are outdated.

The samba port of freebsd has been deleted https://www.freshports.org/net/samba

Answer (score 1):

this isn't a job for samba, which implements Windows file sharing, but for `smbclient`, which implements *accessing* windows shares.

Now, as far as I can tell, FreeBSD lumps `smbclient` into the Samba packaging, but the point is that the Samba package is called [`samba416`](https://www.freshports.org/net/samba416/) (The version packaged is Samba 4.16.xx).

So, you were on the right path, just that the package is called `samba416`, not `samba`. (I'm not a FreeBSD user, so that's as far as my advice can go.)

Comment: thanks. I will look into this, and see if I can do it.